SVG Filter Safari Issue
folks,
I'm having a problems with the following SVG filter. In every other browser it works completely fine, however in Safari is it not applied at all. Could you help me resolve this issue. I'm aware of the problems in the browser concerning the filters yet I would love to hear a Senior opinion on the matter:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-filters">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter-gooey">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6" result="blur"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="gooey"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="gooey" operator="atop"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>`

Thank you for your time!
I tried adjusting the stdDeviation in the feGaussianBlur element and the values in the feColorMatrix
Edit:
I've managed to fix the issue by making sure all of the elements are of the same type yet a new issue appeared in Safari - a trail is left behind the animation. Here are some pictures:
Animation On
Animation After

This filter works fine for me on iOS Safari. (FWIW - there is no "mode" in feColorMatrix - it should be "type" (mode is only used for feBlend) - still works, but it's incorrect). I hope you're not trying to use the old Windows Safari for testing - that is ancient and never had good filter support.

Thank you for the reply and advice! I'm using the Version 17.5 of Safari on Sonoma 14.5. iOS Safari is fine, yet macOS is a completely different story. The filter is not rendered at all...

The current SVG filter usually works even in iOS Safari. But I've also issues once the "goo" element is animated/transitioned. Quite likely it's a SVG rendering issue - therefore better add an rendered HTML/SVG output instead of Vue/framework specific template code.

There are several variants to write the "gooey" filter. I once built a tool to play around with them. While the errors I was tacklling at the time are long fixed, maybe you can find a working version there.

That filter definition works fine in Mac Safari 14.2. You might be getting something wrong elsewhere. What's in the CSS class svg-filters?

I've managed to fix the issue by making sure all of the elements are of the same type yet a new issue appeared in Safari - a trail is left behind the animation. I've uploaded pictures in the OP

Fixed the issue with the following tweaks:

Rewrote the whole html template and made sure that everything is inside one element and there is a specific background applied to it;
The main problem was coming because I was using GSAP to animate the elements' movement and scale. However, Safari is not very good with applying SVG filter and scale animation at the same time. Disabled the scale animation for the Safari browser.

Thank you everyone for your contributions and advice!

Please consider to make your answer more applicable for other users by adding some working code examples – ideally running snippets illustrating your findings. The way it's currently  written is very specific to your own project. For instance, some parts like animation were not included in your answer so we can't really follow your steps that finally fixed the safari related issues. Besides, this post may also attract future answers based on fixed-Safari bugs ... or new ones. BTW you would most certainly gain a lot of reputation points - yay ;)
